# Sum of two independent random variables: Inconsistent CDF

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

I have two random continuous RV $X$ and $Y$ and the sum $Z=X+Y$. I am trying to derive the pdf from the first principle but somehow I could not get the results to agree.

--

Let $Y\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $X$ be a CRV with the pdf $f_X(x) = 2x$ with the support $[0, 1]$.

We have
\begin{align}
F_Z(z) &= \Pr(Z\le z) = \Pr(X+Y\le z)\\
&= \int_{y=0}^{1}\int_{x=0}^{z-y} f_{XY}(x,y) \ dxdy\\
&= \int_{y=0}^{1}\int_{x=0}^{z-y} f_{X}(x)f_Y(y) \ dxdy\\
&= \int_{y=0}^{1}\int_{x=0}^{z-y} 2x \ dxdy
\end{align}

Now here is where things get weird...
\begin{align}
F_Z(z) 
&= \int_{y=0}^{1}\int_{x=0}^{z-y} 2x \ dxdy\\
&=\int_{y=0}^{1} (z-y)^2 \ dy\\
&= z^2 - z + \frac{1}{3}
\end{align}

As you can see, the support for $Z$ should be $[0, 2]$ but clearly $F_Z(0)\ne0$ and $F_Z(2)\ne1$.

When I tried again with a different order of integration, I get
\begin{align}
F_Z(z) 
&= \int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{y=0}^{z-x} 2x \ dydx\\
&= \int_{x=0}^{1}2x(z-x) \ dx\\
&= z - \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}
which makes even less sense since I am integrating over the same triangle.

If anyone could point out my mistake I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the "support on $[0,1]$" when you simply write $2x$ in the integrand.  It should be $2x\cdot1_{x\in[0,1]}$, which has the effect of changing the upper limit from $z-y$ to $\min\{1,\max\{z-y,0\}\}$.

\begin{align*}
F_Z(z)&=\int_0^1\int_0^{z-y} 2x\cdot1_{x\in[0,1]}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{\min\{1,\max\{z-y,0\}\}} 2x\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\min\{1,(\max\{z-y,0\})^2\}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\dots
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

You have several cases. For $z\in (0,1)$ the area of integration is the triangle $(0,0),(z,0),(0,z)$ (so $y$ does not go to $1$!). For $z\in (1,2)$ it's a complex shape (the rectangle minus the triangle $(1,1),(1,z-1),(z-1,1)$ so the limits of integration should be fixed accordingly.